# how to enable SwitchPreference from anather activity in android

Tags: android

I have a setting screen in my Application and i want to enable switchpreference from settings screen from my LoginActivity. so can anyone suggest me how to do this?

when clicked on login then in background my switchpreference is also on without going to setting screen .